Hibernate Querydsl Projections.constructor N+1 problem
I don't get how hibernate operate in same condition(to me), but act differently.
let's say that I have entity(root entity) that has nested 1:N entities
public class RootEntity{
  private String name;
  private List<ChildEntity> child; 
}

public class ChildEntity{
  private String cname;
  private List<CChildEntity> cchild;
}

public class CChildEntity{
  private String ccname;
}

public record RootDto(
  private String name,
  private List<ChildDto> child
){
  public RootDto(RootEntity r){
    this(
      r.getName(),
      r.getChild().stream().map(ChildDto::new).toList()
    );
  }
}

public record ChildDto(
  private String cname,
  private List<CChildDto> cchild
){
  public ChildDto(ChildEntity c){
    this(c.getCname(), c.getCchild().stream.map(CChildDto::new).toList());
    
  }
}

public record CChildDto(
  private String ccname
){
  public CChildDto(CChildEntity cc){
    this(cc.getCcname());
  }
}

and trying to retrieve all with QueryDSL:
@Transactional
public List<RootDto> get(){
  JPAQuery<RootDto> query = queryFactory
    .selectDistinct(Projections.constructor(ResponseDto.class, RootEntity))
    .from(root)
    .leftJoin(root.childs, child)
    .leftJoin(child.cchilds, cchild)

  List<RootDto> content = query.fetch()
  return content;
}

Above execution causes N+1 problem, which I did not expected/
But below does not have N+1 problem.
Why is that?
Those two are looks like same operation to me.
@Transactional
public List<RootDto> get(){
  JPAQuery<RootDto> query = queryFactory
    .selectDistinct(root)
    .from(root)
    .leftJoin(root.childs, child)
    .leftJoin(child.cchilds, cchild)

  List<RootDto> content = query.fetch().stream().map(RootDto::new).toList();
  return content;
}

and if Projections.contsructor does not support EntityManager to initialize those entity via Dtos, why is that?
And how could that  be possible? (again, looks similar to me)
